# How to prevent users from modifying other users' data?

Tags: java, security, spring-security

Scenario: A photo sharing website that allows users to upload pictures. Users can delete or edit their photos. The delete and edit methods are Post methods. These methods use photo ID to locate the photo and modify it. The photos are obtained by current authenticated user information like:`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();`

So what if user A wants to delete a photo ID of user B, and A writes a post method with JavaScript and delete user B's photo.

Is that possible? Or is this practice problematic?

Comment: You need some sort of "List" to "Control Access". http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#domain-acls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to write a service layer that allows deletion based on permissions.

This would prevent users from deleting assets they shouldn't.

Each request would validate this to ensure a user who does not have rights to delete cant.

It all depends on how your domain manages permission, if the assets have specific owners then you could use the `SecurityContextHolder`, otherwise you need to implement your own logic.

Comment: The way I was considering is having a column user_id in the photo table, and check if the photo belongs to the current authenticated user. But I think this is wasting a lot of resources, resulting in a lot of database operations

Comment: @Tong Actually I think that's a pretty fair solution. It ensures only the owner can amend.

Comment: @Tong One database read when you already have the photo in the scope is a simple comparison. Not a waste of resources at all.

Comment: Yes. But if there are more domain classes. Say there are photo, album, video. I need to associate every class with user?

Comment: @Tong Then in reality it's down to how you design the domain. You can have a owner (user) that is a related to each entity, like a foreign key. Using something like JPA would create these joins for you. There really is no right answer, it's what is appropriate for the implementation.

Comment: Thank you Geditdk. I think for some simple case this method is good enough. But for some more complicated cases, we may need Control Access List. This is my first heard of it. I will check it out.